# need to get the left property of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get the left property of an object

i've tried

```
$('myobject').left() //it doesn't work`
$('myobject').css().left() //invalid property
$('myobject').css('left') //invalid property
```

i've been using offset().left which is totally wrong, i need to get the left property of an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myobject').position().left
```

For top as well, drop the left.

```
$('#myobject').position()
```

Comment: so far position().left has worked for me thank for that that's what i was looking for cheers

Answer (score 2):

Put this on the end: `.replace(/%|in|cm|mm|em|ex|pt|pc|px/,'')` It will remove all CSS units from the result:

jQuery way:

```
$('#myobject').css('left').replace(/%|in|cm|mm|em|ex|pt|pc|px/,'');
```

standard way:

```
document.getElementById('myobject').style.left.replace(/%|in|cm|mm|em|ex|pt|pc|px/,'');
```

hybrid:

```
$('#myobject')[0].style.left.replace(/%|in|cm|mm|em|ex|pt|pc|px/,'');
```

Comment: Well done. sometime .position() is different from .css('left')

Answer (score 1):

the css left?

```
$('#myobject').css('left')
```

Comment: i downloaded jquery 1.6 and it worked the only problem is it return 200px instead of 200 i just wanted a number not px at the end

Comment: just surround it with `parseInt()` then

Answer (score 0):

try  ***position.left***

### [working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n63LQ/)

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/position)